# How to determine which Linux program is keeping monitor awake?

Tags: linux, dpms

After I lock the screen and leave my machine alone, sometimes the monitor sleeps after some delay but sometimes it doesn't. I have already set system settings to allow monitor sleeping but I suspect some errant program is quietly preventing the monitor from sleeping. I want the monitor sleeping to be predictable and truly controlled by the system settings.

How can I find out which program is preventing monitor sleep, at at least why the monitor fails to sleep when it happens?

If the answer to the question is distro-specific, my distro is Arch Linux, but an answer for another popular distro like Fedora or Ubuntu would be equally helpful.

Comment: there are a [question in askubuntu about this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1339826/determine-what-process-is-keeping-my-screensaver-from-activating) and a [question about sleep,which might also help](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1071514/how-to-find-a-program-which-is-preventing-sleeping)